# Angular js custom filter undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular JS and working with custom filter for Month in Date of Birth option.

The function monthName has been defined inside the controller.

When i try to run the file an error :-

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: monthName is not defined
```

HTML :-

```
<select ng-model="main.userdobmonth" ng-change="main.getMonthDays()">
    <option ng-selected="{{$index+1==main.userdobmonth}}" value="{{$index+1}}" 
            ng-repeat="a in main.rangeDate(12) track by $index">{{$index+1 | monthName}}</option>
</select>
```

My controller code :-

```
angular.module('HC', ['ngAnimate'])
    .controller('MainController', MainController)
    .filter('monthName', monthName);

// Inject dependencies
MainController.$inject = ['U', 'M', 'S', '$filter', '$upload', '$timeout'];

function MainController(U, M, S, $filter, $upload, $scope, $timeout) {

    // ....

    function monthName() {
        return function (monthNumber) { //1 = January
            var monthNames = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
                'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
            return monthNames[monthNumber - 1];
        }
    }

}
```

Any solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You defined `monthName` inside of `MainController`. As the result it's a local variable which is not accessible outside where you try to use it. Solution is to move it outside.

```
function MainController (U, M, S, $filter, $upload, $scope, $timeout) { ... }

function monthName () { ... }
```